# Delphi XE8 doesn't compile anymore after reinstalling

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-xe8

I had to reinstall Delphi XE8, and when I tried to compile "Hello world!" in debug configuration to test the installation I got the following error:

> Checking project dependencies...
>   brcc32 command line for "Project1.vrc"
>   dcc command line for "Project1.dpr"
>   [dcc32 Error] E1026 File not found: 'Controls.res'
>   Failed
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:00.9

I can understand that, since I only find `controls.res` files in the `\release` folders (32-bit and 64-bit). But when I try to compile in release configuration I get the following:

> Checking project dependencies...
>   Compiling Project1.dproj (Release, Win32)
>   brcc32 command line for "Project1.vrc"
>   dcc command line for "Project1.dpr"
>   [dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(1): F1027 Unit not found: 'System' or binary equivalents (.dcu)
>   Failed
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:00.2

`System.dcu` exists in both 32-bit and 64-bit folders, for both debug and release configurations, though.

Can I fix these errors somehow by pointing the compiler to the right folders? If so, how? And shouldn't these pointers be set during install in the first place?

**update**
This install was a repair install, i.e. I ran the install over the existing installation.
I also tried a clean install, after a complete uninstall (using Revo Uninstaller Pro). Unfortunately, same results.

Comment: That it can't find System anymore is usually a hint that some directories are not properly set up, either in the project or in the actual setup (including PATH environment variable). Was this an existing "Hello World!" app or one you just created?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Created myself. Just a button on a VCL form, and an OnClick event: ShowMessage().

Comment: Then I can't help you. You could try a repair using setup.exe (yes, I know this is a new install, but still, sometimes that helps).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No worries. The installation I mentioned was a repair install. I just uninstalled everything and currently am installing again. Hope that helps. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Check your actual PATH setting after the install - anything weird in there?

Comment: @JorisGroosman When you are uninstalling Delphi I strongly recommend you use its own uninstaller rather than some third party uninstaller. The main reason for this is that Delphi uninstaller also ask you if you want to keep or remove existing settings. This is used so that you can install Delphi updates which require complete reinstallation without loosing any of your settings. Using third party uninstallers like Revo Uninstaler might not remove Delphi settings and thus lead to broken installations.

Comment: @JorisGroosman Also if you are installing one of Delphi XE8 updates make sure you are using correct installation. Users that have active software maintenance subscription for Delphi have different installation than the regular users have. So installing a subscription version without having proper serial for it would result in having of a non working Delphi. For more info on this check the Embarcaderos official support pages.

Comment: With regards to the second error, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5517308/62576 may give you something to investigate.